# Why Java method doesnt throw exception in test class?

Tags: java, exception

Why cant i throw exception from takeDamage method in Mammal object and catch it in Test class where that object is created?

```
    package animals;
    public class Mammal extends Animal{
      public final boolean predation, herbivory;
      public String hairColor;

      public Mammal() {
        super();
        this.predation = rand.nextBoolean();
        this.herbivory = rand.nextBoolean();
        this.hairColor = colors[rand.nextInt(8)];
      }

      public Mammal(boolean predation, boolean herbivory, String hairColor) {
        super();
        this.predation = predation;
        this.herbivory = herbivory;
        this.hairColor = hairColor;
      }
      public Mammal(boolean predation, boolean herbivory, String hairColor, String name, boolean sex) {
        super(name, sex);
        this.predation = predation;
        this.herbivory = herbivory;
        this.hairColor = hairColor;
      }

      public void takeDamage(int damage) throws TakeDamageException{
        if(damage < 1) {
          throw new TakeDamageException("Damage cant be negative!");
        }
        else this.health -= damage;
      }
```

I try to catch the exception thrown by takeDamage method, but i get: exception TakeDamageException is never thrown in body of corresponding try statement

and: unreported exception TakeDamageException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
       mammal.takeDamage(-123);

```
 import animals.*;

    public class Test extends Mammal {

      public static void main(String[] args){
        Mammal mammal = new Mammal();
        System.out.println(mammal.doDamage());
        System.out.println(mammal.getEnergy());
        try {
           mammal.takeDamage(-123);
        }
         catch(TakeDamageException e) {
           System.out.println("Couldnt take damage:" + e);
        }
      }
    }
```

Defined my exception class as:

```
public class TakeDamageException extends Exception {
  public TakeDamageException(String message)  {
    super(message);
  }
  public TakeDamageException() {
  }
}
```

Comment: From what you are showing this line would not compile:  takeDamage(-123);  Changed to mammal.takeDamage(-123); it should and you should see the exception.

Comment: Sry made mistake i do compile it as mammal.takeDamage(-123);

Comment: I got the exception with your code on my side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A far more concise example works just fine.  I disagree that test should inherit from Mammal, but left it in there for my example:

Mammal.java:

```
public class Mammal {
int health =500;
  public void takeDamage(int damage) throws Exception{
    if(damage < 1) {
      throw new Exception("Damage cant be negative!");
    }
    else this.health -= damage;
  }
```

}

Test.java:

```
public class MTest extends Mammal {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Mammal m = new Mammal();
    try {
        m.takeDamage(-100);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");
    }
}
```

}

You are probably trying to do too much at one time.  Baby steps.

Comment: Thank you very much. Maybe do you have an idea why it doesnt work if I try to throw custom Exception?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an underlying issue: Referencing the non-static method `takeDamage(int)` from a static context. Even though you're working within a subclass of `Mammal`, you need to reference an instance of it to use that method.

Comment: Sry made mistake, i call it as mammal.takeDamage(-123);